# SCNLight cast shadow in all direction

Tags: ios, scenekit

Suppose we have a room where the lamp is right in the middle of the room, both vertically and horizontally. How can it cast shadows in all directions? Is there anyway to fake it? I have objects that move. `SCNLightTypeSpot` can cast shadows in a cone, but that doesn't work in this situation.

Comment: Does a 360º spotlight work?  (I haven't tested it.)

Comment: why is the spot light useless?

Comment: how to configure SCNLightTypeSpot lighting in every direction incl. to cast shadows? am I missing something?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: nope, i couldn't find any solution :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet it to have multiple lights.

As Toyos said, a light that shines in every direction is an omni light, but considering the shadow rendering technique used (pretty much, a camera).

If you are comfortable with OpenGL, you could implement it easily. There a re resources online on how to approach it such as [this GPUGems article](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch12.html) about cubemaps or [this more recent paper](http://www.cimat.mx/~alberto/Paper.pdf) for a new technique using paraboloids.

You could also suggest these to Apple engineers using the bug reporter! I'm sure a lot of games and applications would benefit from Omnidirectional shadows.

Comment: i guess the your suggestions apply for volumetric lights as well. thank you.

Comment: Actually, volumetric lights are pretty easy to fake!

Look into GodRays GLSL effects, they shouldn't be too hard to port to SCNTechnique.

Answer (score 3):

What you would need is an omni light that supports casting shadows. As the documentation of "castsShadows" says, this is currently not supported by omni lights. You should file a bug request to Apple.